# Nested TabHost in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-tabhost, android-tabs

I am trying to use nested TabHost in android with compile sdk 19.

I want to create parent tabs in FagmentActivity with PatentTab1, ParentTab2, ParentTab3, ParentTab4 And ParentTab5. In ParentTab1 I am having another TabHost with two tabs ChildTab1, ChildTab2.

In ChildTab1 I want to perform some function and replace the ChildTab1 fragment by ResultFragment.

To do this I have written the following code in ChildTab1 fragment on onButtonClick event as follow

```
FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(android.R.id.tabcontent, new ResultFragment(), "result_tab");
ft.commit();
```

But on button click it is replacing the ParentTab's tab container, not ChildTab's tab container.

I want to replace result fragment in ChildTab container.

Could you please help me do this?

Comment: Try using `getChildFragmentManager` from the Fragment instead of `getSupportFragmentManager` which is for the Activity

Comment: Thanks for reply. That was my mistake, I wrote getSupportFragmentManager() in question but I am using same getChildFragmentManager().